# Want to get session id in my header location path

Tags: php

Here I attached my code

```
 $id=$_SESSION['id'];
 header ('Location:http://siaea.com/?page_id=833&location_id=$id');
```

I want to get `$id` in above path. Please help me.

Comment: `header("Location:http://siaea.com/?page_id=833&location_id={$_SESSION['id']}"); exit;`

Comment: Use like this `header ("Location:http://siaea.com/?page_id=833&location_id=".$_SESSION['id']); die();`

Answer (score 2):

Change single quotes to double, php consider single quotes as string, to parse variable you need to use double quotes :

```
 header ("Location:http://siaea.com/?page_id=833&location_id=$id");
 exit();
```

Comment: OP should be sure to put `exit()` after the header location, if he hasn't already

Answer (score 1):

Replace with this one:-

```
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
header ("Location:http://siaea.com/?page_id=833&location_id=".$id);
```